# How to remove an element from an array included in an Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build an application, using MongoDB and nodejs. 
I have a model *Ride*, which contains an array of userID called *steps*. I'd like to delete one userID entry from a Ride specified by its own RideID.

I have tried the following code, but it's not working, an error is always raised

```
router.post('/quitRide',async (req,res)=>{
    let userID = req.body.userID; //userID to be deleted
    let rideID = req.body.rideID; //rideID of the Ride we want to access

    Ride.find({_id:rideID})
    .exec()
    .then(t => {
      t[0].steps.splice(t[0].steps.indexOf(userID), 1);
      res.status(200);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({error : err}))
  })
```

Here's the error I get :

> {error: "erreurTypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"}

It seems like steps are somehow not accessible

Comment: Add a `console.log( t[0] );` before the problematic line (or use a debugger to inspect it).

Comment: Is it possible that there are some Rides with no `steps` (maybe a newly created Ride?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$pull`, for more go to [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

```
router.post('/quitRide',async (req,res)=>{
    let userID = req.body.userID; // userID to be deleted
    let rideID = req.body.rideID; // rideID of the Ride we want to access

    Ride.findOneAndUpdate({_id:rideID}, { $pull: { steps: userId } })
    .exec()
    .then(t => {
      // response with success
      res.status(200);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({error : err}))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Lodash** `Remove` function to remove the elements from the array.
you can install the npm package by running this command `npm i --save lodash.remove` and then do the changes in your code.

```
    router.post('/quitRide',async (req,res)=>{
        let userID = req.body.userID; //userID to be deleted
        let rideID = req.body.rideID; //rideID of the Ride we want to access

        Ride.find({_id:rideID})
        .exec()
        .then(t => {
          _.remove(t[0].steps,userID);
            console.log(t[0].steps)//which contains your array without userID
           res.status(200);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json({error : err}))
      })
```

*Don't forget to import/require the lodash package* and you can find the documentation on below link

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#remove